# Dart convert data to custom class

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function `Future<T?> getDocById<T>(String id) aysnc {}`, it gets the data from web and return the value with type `T`. How can I convert any incoming data from web to a given type?

use case - `class User{ String name; User(this.name);}`
now, `await getDocById<User>()` how can I convert the data to type User inside `getDocById` function? in another case - `getDocById<Boo>` it should get data from web and convert it to Boo and return

Answer (score 0):

Since I just answered a similar question I am copying the code into here. However, if you have an unknown `T` incoming, you need to distinguish cases based on what is incoming. Without this you want be able to convert a `bool` or int `into` a `String name`.

Create a method in one of the classes

```dart
class A {
 A(this.a);
 final int a;
 
 B toB() {
    return B(
    b: a,
  }
}  

class B {
 B(this.b);
 final int b;
}
```

To be used like `final bInstance = aInstance.toB();` meaning you declared somewhere `aInstance = A(1);`